# Showing polygons/shapes in r leaflet minimap

Tags: r, leaflet, r-leaflet

I have a map of the US with a polygon data layer for a choropleth map and want to show an inset map of Alaska via the minimap function. The basic code looks like

```
leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% addPolygons(params ...) %>% addMiniMap(params...)
```

When I do so, I see the map of alaska, but it doesn't show my polygons which makes the inset a bit pointless. Are there any solutions to showing the polygon/shapes layers within the minimap?

If this isn't feasible, are there any other methods of showing the inset?